# How to integrate web calculator into excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am facing a problem to integrate an online calculator into an excel sheet that refreshes itself automatically every minute.

Is it done by formula or by VBA?

Try to search the formula but nothing found

> WEBSERVICE(url])

It is not what I expect

Answer (score 1):

Go to "DATA" tab then click "From Web" then add web address in appeared browser and click to insert the required data in your excel workbood